# How to debug a view error in NancyFx?

Tags: c#, razor, nancy

I have a project where I'm porting over some code from ASP.Net MVC to use Nancy instead. I'm continuing to use Razor for the view engine in the new project.  And one of my views is giving me the following exception:

```
RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
at RazorOutput.RazorView.Execute()
at Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase`1.ExecuteView(String body, IDictionary`2 sectionContents)
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object , Object )
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid3[T0,T1,T2](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object , Object )
at Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.RazorViewEngine.<>c__DisplayClass27.<RenderView>b__26(Stream stream)
at Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.HtmlHelpers`1.Partial(String viewName, Object modelForPartial)
at RazorOutput.RazorView.Execute()
at Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase`1.ExecuteView(String body, IDictionary`2 sectionContents)
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object , Object )
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid3[T0,T1,T2](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)
at Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.RazorViewEngine.<>c__DisplayClass27.<RenderView>b__26(Stream stream)
at Nancy.Responses.MaterialisingResponse.PreExecute(NancyContext context)
```

Now, this is in some sense an easy enough error to fix: just prevent the null from being deferenced, right? The problem I'm having is I don't know which parts of my model and view it is having problems with. So what I'm asking is if there is a way to get a better error message out of Nancy here? If I could get it to tell me a line number in the view, or the name of the null object it can't bind, that would make debugging dramatically easier.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping this would work better than RazorEngine, but I see NancyFx has the same weakness.  Really disappointing to see this is still a common Razor Thing in 2017...

My hack was to add a property for source file name and line number and add code to update those by hand.  Really ugly, and the number was less a reference to the actual line number and more just a unique identifier in the file, but it does get you more localized information.

```
@{ Model.LineNumber = "62"; } <div>@Model.Example</div>
```

I'd love to hear if anyone found a better solution in any Razor solution that can be run outside of an HttpContext.